# Pandas for each new value in a column, remove the following two rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, fillna

I have the following dataframe:

```
time   alarm
0       0
1       1
2       0
3       1
4       1
5       1
6       1
7       0
8       0
9       1
10      0
```

The column `alarm` represents an alarm. If it rings, it takes value 1. 
Each time the alarm rings, I want to "silence" the next two rows. Then, if it rings again after the silenced period, I want to silence the next two rows, and so on.

In other words, I want to obtain the following dataframe:

```
time   alarm    silenced
0       0       no
1       1       no
2       0       yes
3       1       yes
4       1       no
5       1       yes
6       1       yes
7       0       no
8       0       no
9       1       no
10      0       yes
```

I managed to do it using a for loop or a lambda function, but I have to speed up the computation. 
Can somebody help me? Thank you in advance!

---

P.S.
Since I will eventually remove the "silenced" rows, a solution that directly removes such rows will also be accepted. In such case, the result should be:

```
time   alarm
0       0
1       1
4       1
7       0
8       0
9       1
```

---

MY ATTEMPT using a for loop in an auxiliary function:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"time":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], "alarm":[0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0]})
df

def fun_silence(df):
    
    # bool: if True,  we are in a "silent" period 
    #       if False, we can consider the current time as a possible alarm
    flag_silent = False
    
    # time of the *last* alarm
    alarm_time = np.nan
    
    # loop over rows
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        
        # if we are in a silent period
        if flag_silent:
            
            # if 2 time steps passed from the last alarm, we end the silent period
            if row['time'] - alarm_time > 2:
                flag_silent = False
                
            # otherwise, we mark this row as silenced
            else:
                df.at[index, 'silenced'] = 1
          
        # if there is an alarm and we are not in a silent period
        if row['alarm'] == 1 and not flag_silent:
            # save the alarm time
            alarm_time = row['time']
            # enter in a silent period
            flag_silent = True
            
    return df
    
df['silenced'] = 0
df_silenced = fun_silence(df)
df_silenced
```

Comment: can you show us the code that you've tried?

Comment: yep, you are right, I have added it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can not avoid the for-loop in this problem but you can certainly optimize the function and then compile it using numba to achieve C like speed on large datasets

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def silence(alarm):
    count = 0
    for a in alarm:
        if count > 0:
            yield True
            count -= 1
        elif count == 0 and a == 1:
            count = 2
            yield False
        else:
            yield False

    
df['silenced'] = [*silence(df['alarm'].to_numpy())]
```

---

```
    time  alarm  silenced
0      0      0     False
1      1      1     False
2      2      0      True
3      3      1      True
4      4      1     False
5      5      1      True
6      6      1      True
7      7      0     False
8      8      0     False
9      9      1     False
10    10      0      True
```

Comment: I like this idea, thank you. I also suspect that it is not possible to avoid the for loop. I was looking for a way to use pandas.fillna(limit=2) in this problem, but I cannot find a way out of it.

Comment: @NiccolòAjroldi for loop is not always bad :-). happy coding!

Comment: Oh not bad, but certainly slow :)

Comment: I should add that I need the function to receive a dataframe and return a dataframe, since I will call it on each group of a groupby: 
df = df.groupby('my_id').apply(fun_silence)

Comment: @NiccolòAjroldi In that case, you can call the `silence` function per group: `df.groupby('my_id')['alarm'].transform(lambda a: silence(a.to_numpy()))`